# Expo and Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, expo

I am thinking of this stack to create my first mobile app.

My question is, does Expo has a documentation for integrating third-party API, in my case a Rails API. And if no, it should not be a problem at the stage when you export the project as "Standalone project" to integrate a Rails API right?

Comment: When you say this stack..what do you mean ? also Stack Overflow is for specific programing problems not about definining architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backend and mobile development are different things. Expo is just a library on the top of react native that just uses javascript.

The backend language is just a detail.. does not matter if the project is made with Rails, Laravel, or other framework, because in general they use a HTTP endpoint to create a integration based on a `REST` architecture

So, the integration is the same compared with other JS projects.

To integrate you just need to make a HTTP request to your API, using the built-in `fetch` method or a library like `axios`

Check this link for more details: https://codeburst.io/integrating-react-native-apps-with-back-end-code-using-fetch-api-8aeb83dfb428